# Adsense scripts references - single or multiple copies per page

Tags: javascript, adsense

I'm currently using adsense code on the page as it was generated by Adsense->New Ad Unit.

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXXXX"
     data-ad-format="auto">
</ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

There are three ad blocks per page, so I'm referencing adsbygoogle.js three times.

I've tried to remove all but the first reference to adsbygoogle.js and it seems to work just fine.

So the question is - is it safe to use just a single reference to Adsense javascript, both in terms of risk of breaking the functionality and violating adsense TOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is on the support pages of google adsense: [No, this is not necessary, adsbygoogle.js can be loaded once.](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666?hl=en&ref_topic=1307438)